# Commercial Admin Levels

Tags: spatial-database, google-maps-api, administrative-boundaries, data

I'm looking to find commercially available admin boundaries (0 through lowest available) for the world that I can place into a user-friendly interface that allows the non-technical user (ie someone who has never heard of a shapefile) to select what boundaries are preferred for generating the map visuals.

Could someone please point me in the direction of what vendors offer this kind of dataset that could be pulled into my own commercial application? Is this a Tomnod kind of thing? Google? ESRI? My assumption is that OSM availability is too patchy for this.

Answer (score 1):

Natural Earth data might be what you're after:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

I would have suggested TeleNav, but looks like [they've gone to OSM](http://www.zdnet.com/telenav-announces-switch-to-openstreetmap-data-and-sdk-launch-with-offline-mapping-support-7000029612/)...

Comment: My concern here is that it's not supported by a commercial vendor so reliability over time might degrade. Also, not sure it has admin levels at lower levels available.

Comment: @user32563 any further luck on this?